# Python Crypto AES 128 with PKCS7Padding different outputs from Swift vs Python

Tags: python, swift, cryptography, encryption-symmetric, frida

The output produced by crypto with following key

```
key = base64.b64decode('PyxZO31GlgKvWm+3GLySzAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=') (16 bytes)
```

and the
`message =  "y_device=y_C9DB602E-0EB7-4FF4-831E-8DA8CEE0BBF5"`

My `IV` object looks like this:
`iv = base64.b64decode('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==')`

Objective C `CCCrypt` produces the following hash `4Mmg/BPgc2jDrGL+XRA3S1d8vm02LqTaibMewJ+9LLuE3mV92HjMvVs/OneUCLD4`

It appears to be using `AlgorithmAES128` uses `PKCS7Padding` with the key provided above.

I'm trying to implement the same crypto encode functionality to get an output like `4Mmg/BPgc2jDrGL+XRA3S1d8vm02LqTaibMewJ+9LLuE3mV92HjMvVs/OneUCLD4`

This is what I've been able to put so far

```
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad
from Crypto . Cipher import AES
class MyCrypt():
    def __init__(self, key, iv):
        self.key = key
        self.iv = iv
        self.mode = AES.MODE_CBC
   
    def encrypt(self, text):
      cryptor = AES.new(self.key, self.mode, self.iv)
      length = 16
      text = pad(text, 16)
      self.ciphertext = cryptor.encrypt(text)
      return self.ciphertext


key = base64.b64decode('PyxZO31GlgKvWm+3GLySzAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=')
IV = base64.b64decode('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==')
plainText = 'y_device=y_C9DB602E-0EB7-4FF4-831E-8DA8CEE0BBF5'.encode('utf-8')
crypto = MyCrypt(key, IV)
encrypt_data = crypto.encrypt(plainText)
encoder = base64.b64encode(encrypt_data)
print(encrypt_data, encoder)
```

This produces the following output `Pi3yzpoVhax0Cul1VkYoyYCivZrEliTDBpDbqZ3dD1bwTUycstAF+MLSTIjSMiQj` instead of `4Mmg/BPgc2jDrGL+XRA3S1d8vm02LqTaibMewJ+9LLuE3mV92HjMvVs/OneUCLD4`
`

Which isn't my desired output.
should I not be using `MODE_ECB`, or am I using `key` as intended ?

To add more context

I'm naive to Crypto/ Objective C.

I'm currently pentesting an app, which does some hashing behind the scenes.

Using frida I'm tracing these function calls, and I see the following get populated for swift Objc calls.

`CCCrypt(operation: 0x0, CCAlgorithm: 0x0, CCOptions: 0x1, keyBytes: 0x1051f8639, keyLength: 0x10, ivBuffer: 0x1051f8649, inBuffer: 0x2814bd890, inLength: 0x58, outBuffer: 0x16f1c5d90, outLength: 0x60, outCountPtr: 0x16f1c5e10)`

Where

```
CCCrypt(operation: 0x0, CCAlgorithm: 0x0, CCOptions: 0x1, keyBytes: 0x1051f8639, keyLength: 0x10, ivBuffer: 0x1051f8649, inBuffer: 0x280e41530, inLength: 0x2f, outBuffer: 0x16f1c56c0, outLength: 0x30, outCountPtr: 0x16f1c5710)
In buffer:
            0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F  0123456789ABCDEF
280e41530  79 5f 64 65 76 69 63 65 3d 79 5f 43 39 44 42 36  y_device=y_C9DB6
280e41540  30 32 45 2d 30 45 42 37 2d 34 46 46 34 2d 38 33  02E-0EB7-4FF4-83
280e41550  31 45 2d 38 44 41 38 43 45 45 30 42 42 46 35     1E-8DA8CEE0BBF5
Key:  16 47
            0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F  0123456789ABCDEF
1051f8639  3f 2c 59 3b 7d 46 96 02 af 5a 6f b7 18 bc 92 cc  ?,Y;}F...Zo.....
IV:  16
            0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F  0123456789ABCDEF
1051f8649  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
```

I use https://opensource.apple.com/source/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto-36064/CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h to reference the type of encryption happening based on pointers i.e for `Options` argument the following is passed `0x1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> key = base64.b64decode('PyxZO31GlgKvWm+3GLySzAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=') (16 bytes)

Nope, that's 32 bytes. It's true that only 16 are non-zero, making a really poor key, but if you pass 256 bits, you are doing AES-256, and you'll get a different result than you would from AES-128 using the first 128 bits of that key.

Your title mentions PKCS #7 padding, but it looks like your code is padding with zeros. That will change the results as well.

ECB doesn't use an IV. If you can see that the Swift code is using the IV, you might be able to see what mode it's using too, or you could try CBC as a first guess. ECB is insecure in most cases. Of course, using a fixed IV is also insecure.

Your output is longer than it should be (64 bytes instead of 48). Your attempt to do the padding yourself is probably responsible for this.

From [`<CommonCryptor.h>`,](https://github.com/Apple-FOSS-Mirror/CommonCrypto/blob/master/CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h) we can decode the parameters used in Swift's call to CCCrypt:

| Type | Value | Name | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CCOperation | 0x0 | kCCEncrypt | Symmetric encryption. |
| CCAlgorithm | 0x0 | kCCAlgorithmAES128 | Advanced Encryption Standard, 128-bit block |
| CCOptions | 0x1 | kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | Perform PKCS7 padding. |
| CCOptions | 0x2 | kCCOptionECBMode | Electronic Code Book Mode. ***Default is CBC.*** |

`CCOptions` is a bit field, and `kCCOptionECBMode` is not set, so the default is used.

So this is AES-128 in CBC mode with PKCS #7 padding.

Comment: My mistake, it is indeed 32 bytes. 
How would I use AES 128 - and PKCS #7 padding from what I already have? New to crypto, apologies about naive questions.

Comment: I'm essentially trying to produce an output that I get from Swift code in python, using the same key/ IV.

Comment: I'm using https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/aes.html

I also added more context in the main question, hopefully it should provide you insight on the key/IV and encryption method used in Swift that I'm trying to convert to python

Comment: Would you happen to know if I should use CBC mode? I can't understand if my swift function is using it or not based on the trace call I posted above. It appears that for IV it's passing `00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00` hex value. What would this indicate?

Comment: To pass IV, would it look like this? I'm using  library `binascii` here
`IV = unhexlify('00000000000000000000000000000000')
key = unhexlify('795f6465766963653d795f43394442363032452d304542372d34464`6342d383331452d384441384345453042424635') ` @erickson

Comment: Thank you for the help so far. I've mostly cleaned up the pieces you mentioned. However my output still seems different than from what I get from Swift. You mentioned fix the key as-well. Am I not passing the correct key based on the trace I get from Swift? I've updated the question w/ latest code and output.

Comment: We can see the key has the following hex `3f 2c 59 3b 7d 46 96 02 af 5a 6f b7 18 bc 92 cc` is what I am passing as b64

Comment: @newbieprogrammer095 Looking better. Use this instead of the current `key`: `key = base64.b64decode('PyxZO31GlgKvWm+3GLySzA==')`